# How to nest ASP.NET websites

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

Is it possible to nest one ASP.NET website within another, for example:

http://example.com is an application root
http://example.com/differentsite is also an application root

If it is possible, what should be stuck in the `web.config` file of the parent website to prevent it interfering with the child site?

*Note: This is for .NET 4.0 shared IIS7 hosting*

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can nest web sites by making  folder an application, or adding a virtual folder that points to another application.

You need access to manage IIS on the server to do that, though.

Comment: Thanks, I am able to set application roots on my shared hosting, this worked a treat without any errors, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the nested folder is IIS manager and click on "Convert to Application". This way they can live together. If you want them to run in separate processes so they won't have the same Application Pool settings, Create another application pool and assign one of the sites to it.
BTW, if the site folders are nested, they don't have to always appear in IIS manager as nested. You can add application to the default web site (or create a new site) and point it to the nested folder.

Comment: That's a super answer, thanks, however I cannot access IIS manager on my shared hosting, just a cut down version that allows me to set app roots.