# Create a website Inside SiteCore Site

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, sitecore, sitecore7

I want to do nesting of one site inside SiteCore Site in IIS

I have Created  One site ,One Page(/layout/Sites/Neeraj/LHome.aspx) in it and  mapped it with Layout(/sitecore/content/Home/Sites/Neeraj/Home) and published the solution in SiteCore Root Site(Name :SiteCore2)

MarkUp of LHome.aspx is following :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <p>This is Sample Layout</p>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

For mapping of innersite with SiteCore Site In  Folder  ..I Created Neeraj.config file(path:SiteCore2\App_Config\Include)

Which is as following :

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <sites>
      <site
        patch:before="site[@name='service']"
        inherits="website"
        name="Neeraj"
        hostName="Neeraj.com"
        virtualFolder="/"
        rootPath="/sitecore/content/Home/Sites/Neeraj"
        startItem="/Home"
        database="web"
        domain="extranet"
        disableClientData="true"
        cacheHtml="true"
        htmlCacheSize="10MB"
        registryCacheSize="0"
        viewStateCacheSize="0"
        xslCacheSize="5MB" />


    </sites>

  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

In host file I also made entry for the Site as follows :

```
127.0.0.1   Neeraj.com
```

But When I tried to Browse inner site (Neeraj.com) ...it doesnot appear on Browser

I view the Preview section of SiteCore ..it also shows Blank

I am not able to find any similar Post regarding it ....

**Things I Tried :**

I Refer this post :
[How to nest ASP.NET websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490950/how-to-nest-asp-net-websites)

and convert my virtual directory into application ..still no luck

2.
http://sdn.sitecore.net/FAQ/Administration/Project%20in%20Virtual%20Directory.aspx

This post suggest is to remove

remove Sitecore HTTP Modules in the virtual directory’s web.config

But it dont have web config in virtual directory

3. [Nested virtual directory or application within sitecore site, is it possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795022/nested-virtual-directory-or-application-within-sitecore-site-is-it-possible) 
   it also refers to 2nd post

Any suggestion would be helpful

Comment: what do you mean by 'it doesnot appear on Browser'? 404? blank page? what is the response code? have you published your items?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your correctly, you want to have 2 sites in a single install of Sitecore.

You don't need to nest within a virtual directory.  You can do this based on just the content tree.  Check out this link on [configuration multiple sites](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/Administration/Configuring%20Multiple%20Sites.aspx).

You content tree might look something like this:

> > Site1/
> >
> > > Home
> > >
> > > > Page 1
> > > >
> > > > Page 2
> >
> > Site2/
> >
> > > Home
> > >
> > > > Page 1
> > > >
> > > > Page 2

You need to have a site definition (i.e. similar to the **site** node you already created) for each site.

Site1 Site Definition:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <sites>
      <site
        patch:before="site[@name='website']"
        name="Site1"
        hostName="Site1.com"
        virtualFolder="/"
        rootPath="/sitecore/content/Site1"
        startItem="/Home" />
    </sites>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Site2 Site Definition:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <sites>
      <site
        patch:before="site[@name='website']"
        name="Site2"
        hostName="Site2.com"
        virtualFolder="/"
        rootPath="/sitecore/content/Site2"
        startItem="/Home" />
    </sites>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Lastly, if you want Site2 to be a virtual directory of Site1 (i.e. Site1.com/Site2) then you can use the virtualFolder attribute. see info on the virtualFolder attribute [here](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/Administration/Configuring%20Multiple%20Sites/Adding%20New%20Site/site%20Attribute%20Properties/virtualFolder.aspx) and physicalFolder [here](http://sdn.sitecore.net/SDN5/Articles/Administration/Configuring%20Multiple%20Sites/Adding%20New%20Site/site%20Attribute%20Properties/physicalFolder.aspx).

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <sites>
      <site
        patch:after="site[@name='Site1']"
        name="Site2"
        virtualFolder="/Site2"
        rootPath="/sitecore/content/Site2"
        startItem="/Home" />
    </sites>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: yes , I have Created Virtual Directory insite SiteCore root Site and placed My Site in it . So as per your saying in the last config file ....i dont need hostname attribute there while creating virtual directory ?

Comment: You don't need to create virtual directories. You have only one site in IIS per Sitecore instance. In that instance you can have any number of sites by configuring new "site" nodes in the sitedefinition.config.